# Overriding the default field type in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

models.py

```
class Job(db.Model):

title = db.StringProperty(verbose_name='Project Title:')
description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True, verbose_name='Description:')

created_at = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
budget = db.IntegerProperty()
max_project_duration = db.IntegerProperty()
```

forms.py

```
class JobForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):

def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JobForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['rows'] = '2'
    self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['cols'] = '70' 

class Meta:
    model = Job
```

I want to set the length for title to a longer width. I'm not sure how to manipulate the widget. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in Django 1.2:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import Textarea, TextInput

from my_project.models import Job

class JobForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        widgets = {
          'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': '2', 'cols': '70}),
          'title': TextInput(attrs={'size': '60'}),
        }
```

This is documented at the bottom of the [Widgets page in the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/).